# IBM Watson Speech To Text : Not able to transcribe the text using the Swift SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am using IBM Watson speech to text iOS SDK for transcribing the real-time audio. I have installed it through cocoa pods. I am stuck with an issue (authentication) while transcribing the audio to text.

The installed STT SDK version is `0.38.1`.

I have configured everything, created the service and credential correctly and also making sure `SpeechToText` instantiated with proper `apikey` and `URL`. Whenever I call the `startStreaming` method STT SDK prints some error log, which seems related to the authentication challenge.

Here is the code snippet.

```
let speechToText = SpeechToText(apiKey: Credentials.SpeechToTextAPIKey,iamUrl: Credentials.SpeechToTextURL)
var accumulator = SpeechRecognitionResultsAccumulator()

func startStreaming() {

  var settings = RecognitionSettings(contentType: "audio/ogg;codecs=opus")
  settings.interimResults = true
  let failure = { (error: Error) in print(error) }
  speechToText.recognizeMicrophone(settings: settings, failure: failure) { results in
  accumulator.add(results: results)
  print(accumulator.bestTranscript)

 }
}
```

**Error Logs**

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, 
query={
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
ptcl = htps;
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sdmn = "IBM Watson Gateway(Log-in)";
srvr = "gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net";
sync = syna;
}
```

I have dug into IBM Watson SDK documentation even googled around this issue but did not find any relevant answer.

Comment: I've been having trouble with logging in the past couple of days through their web API. I think there's something going on on IBM's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version[1.0.0](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/releases/tag/1.0.0) of Swift SDK is released with SpeechToTextV1 changes and the below code works for me with Speech to Text service API Key.

You don't have to extensively pass the URL until and unless the service is created in a region other than Dallas. Check the URLs [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text#service-endpoint)

```
import SpeechToTextV1 // If sdk is installed using Carthage. 
import SpeechToText // If sdk is installed as a pod 

let apiKey = "your-api-key"
let speechToText = SpeechToText(apiKey: apiKey)

var accumulator = SpeechRecognitionResultsAccumulator()

func startStreaming() {
    var settings = RecognitionSettings(contentType: "audio/ogg;codecs=opus")
    settings.interimResults = true
    speechToText.recognizeMicrophone(settings: settings) { response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        guard let results = response?.result else {
            print("Failed to recognize the audio")
            return
        }
        accumulator.add(results: results)
        print(accumulator.bestTranscript)
    }
}

func stopStreaming() {
    speechToText.stopRecognizeMicrophone()
}
```

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/tree/1.0.0/Source/SpeechToTextV1)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yes, you are right just tested with service(created in Dallas region) credentials. It is working fine. #IBM released the 1.0.0 version of swift sdk on 6th Dec 2018.

Thanks